How to pack with a small overflow
We are given a set of items with sizes between $0$ and $1$ (the maximum item size is $1$). The sum of all sizes is $S$.
We are given a bin with a capacity of $r\cdot S$, where $r\in (0,1)$. We have to fill the bin (i.e., find a subset of the items with total size at least $r\cdot S$), such that the overflow above the bin capacity should be as small as possible.
An overflow smaller than $1$ is always possible using a simple greedy algorithm: just add items in an arbitrary order until the bin is full. Since the maximum item size is $1$, the overflow is smaller than $1$.
But for some values of $r$, a smaller upper bound can be proved. For example, if $r=1/k$ for some integer $k$, then an overflow of at most $(k-1)/k$ is possible as follows. Draw a line of length $S$, divided into segments such that each segment length equals the size of one item. Cut the line into $k$ parts of length $S/k$. Each part contains some whole items and at most two item fractions. If the items corresponding to the fractions are added, then we get a full basket. As at most $k-1$ items are fractioned, the total overflow over all $k$ baskets is at most $k-1$, so there is at least one basked with overflow at most $(k-1)/k$.
QUESTION: what are other values of $r$, for which a better upper bound on the overflow is possible? In general, given a real number $r$, what is the best possible upper bound on the overflow?

Is there any assumption that you have omitted? Maybe I don't fully understand your question. Let's take $2$ items of size $a$ and $b$, such that $S=1=a+b$. Let's assume $a \gt\gt b$ and $r=b+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon \to 0$. The only attractive option is to fit the bin with $a$, which as a limit will make the overflow $=1$, right? Which means, for this particular selection of items, the bound is $1-r$ given  $r$.

@Srini $r$ is a fixed parameter, it should not depend on the item sizes. In your scenario, given $r$, the item sizes are $b=r-\epsilon$ and $a=1-r+\epsilon$. If $r\leq (1+\epsilon)/2$, then $a\geq r$ and there is a packing with overflow $a-r = 1-2r+\epsilon$. But this is only a single example. The question is: is it always possible to find a packing with overflow at most $1-r$?

Srini's comment and your analysis suggest a different approach: For which values of $r$  can you find scenarios where the smallest overflow is at least $1 -\epsilon$ for any epsilon? I.e., instead of asking for which values of $r$ can you find a smaller bound, ask for which values of $r$ is $1$ the best possible bound? By examining how high of an overflow you can force for each $r$, you get insight into what the upper bounds can be.

First, we show an algorithm for the case where $r=p/q$, where $p$ and $q$ are co-prime.
Using $q-1$ cuts, divide the line into $q$ segments arranged in a cycle. Starting from the start of an item, mark $q$ subsets, each of which contains $p$ segments. As $p$ and $q$ are co-prime, all segments are different. Each subset, with fractions rounded up, defines a full bin. Each fraction occurs exactly once, and the sum of all fractions is $q-1$ (since the first line does not cut any item). Therefore, at least one subset has overflow at most $(q-1)/q = 1-1/q$.
Second, we prove a matching lower bound. For $r=p/q$, we construct a set composed of x items of size $1$.
We have $rx =(p \cdot x)/q$.
We need $p \cdot x - 1 = q \cdot n$, for any natural $n$.
That is, $p \cdot x - 1 = q \cdot n$, so $p \cdot x = q \cdot n + 1$, so $x = (q \cdot n + 1)/p = (q \cdot n)/p + 1/p$.
We need to prove that for a natural number $n$, $(q \cdot n + 1)/p$ is natural.
It will happen when $q \cdot n \mod p = p-1$.
Using the modular inverse of $q$ modulo $p$ ensures a solution to the above equation.
For irrationals $r$, the lower bound of $1$ follows from $1-1/q$ since it is like rational with infinite denominator.

So when $r = p/q$ and $p,q$ are co-prime, we have a tight bound of $1-1/q$. Great!
